# Flutter facebook integration Unhandled exception: type 'Future<dynamic>'

Tags: facebook, dart, flutter

While using facebook sdk for login, I am getting this error when I click facebook button.

```
 flutter: type '_InternalLinkedHashMap<dynamic, dynamic>' is not a 
 subtype of type 'Map<String, Object>'
 [VERBOSE-2:dart_error.cc(16)] Unhandled exception:
type 'Future<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'Future<Null>'
#0      FlutterWebviewPlugin.close (package:flutter_webview_plugin/flutter_webview_plugin.dart:73:36)
#1      FacebookConnect.login (package:flutter_facebook_connect/src/flutter_facebook_connect_base.dart:50:34)
<asynchronous suspension>
 #2      _FacebookLoginButtonState._onPressed 
(package:flutter_facebook_connect/src/facebook_login_button.dart:64:61)
<asynchronous suspension>
 #3      _InkResponseState._handleTap 
(package:flutter/src/material/ink_well.dart:494:14)
 #4      _InkResponseState.build.<anonymous closure> 
(package:flutter/src/material/ink_well.dart:549:30)
 #5      GestureRecognizer.invokeCallback 
(package:flutter/src/gestures/recognizer.dart:102:24)
 #6      TapGestureRecognizer._checkUp 
(package:flutter/src/gestures/tap.dart:161:9)
 #7      TapGestureRecognizer.acceptGesture 
(package:flutter/src/gestures/tap.dart:123:7)
 #8      GestureArenaManager.sweep (package:flutter/src/gest<…>
flutter: type '_InternalLinkedHashMap<dynamic, dynamic>' is not a 
subtype of type 'Map<String, Object>'
```

Here is my code:

```
new FacebookLoginButton(
                                appId: appId,
                                  clientSecret: appSecret,
                                scope: [FacebookAuthScope.publicProfile],
                                cookie: false,
                                onConnect: (api, token){
                                  _connect = api;
                                  print(token);
                                },
                              ),
```

I am not sure where I am doing wrong. Please let me know what this error means.

Here is my flutter doctor summary:

```
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[✓] Flutter (Channel beta, v0.4.4, on Mac OS X 10.13.4 17E202, locale en-IN)
[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK 27.0.3)
[✓] iOS toolchain - develop for iOS devices (Xcode 9.4)
[✓] Android Studio (version 3.1)
[✓] Connected devices (1 available)

• No issues found!
```

Comment: Can you please add the output of `flutter doctor` to your question? I guess the Facebook plugin needs update to new Dart 2 semantics (or you are not using the latest version - check `pubspec.lock`)

Comment: Yes, I've added please check. All seems working fine.

Comment: Did you check you have the latest plugin version?

Comment: I've disabled dart2 mode in setting and its working fine now. :) Thanks

Comment: Its giving error for android now, 
android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class,

How can I define this in Manifest.xml in flutter?

Answer (score 0):

I've resolved the issue by disabling the dart2 mode. From android studio: 
Settings>> Languages & Frameworks >> Flutter.

and then set the 'Run application in Dart 2.0' option to 'Disable Dart 2'

Comment: Just to be sure your are aware of that, this will break with the next Flutter update, because then Flutter will only support Dart 2 mode.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I faced some issues. I've enabled it again. And problem was with my facebook plugin. I was using wrong plugin [flutter_facebook_connect 0.0.4+1](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/flutter_facebook_connect)

Comment: Here is the latest one plugin for facebook. [flutter_facebook_login 1.1.1](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/flutter_facebook_login)